# fastest way to discover nodes on LAN

Tags: networking, device-discovery

I have a larger network about 1000 pcs on LAN

I need to know that what is the fastest way to discover nodes/ pc  on lan for admin pruposes

Abdul Khaliq

Comment: best suites for superuser.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try sending out a ping message but it's unlikely that all nodes will reply to it.

The most reliable way to detect nodes is to perform ARP requests. You'll need to control a node inside the LAN (ARP requests don't pass through routers).

Comment: in .net 3.5 there is ping utility class which is also faster way to discover nodes in .net

Comment: what if the ICMP interface is disabled on the target nodes?